# Infragistics XamChart data point limit?

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics

Is there a recommended amount of data points to be added at once to the xamChart for Infragistics WPF DataVisualization 2011.1? I tried added 60k points at once and my gui just stalled there. Scaled the number down to 4k but still to no avail. My code is as follows

```
Series ECG = new Series();
            ECG.ChartType = ChartType.ScatterLine;
            ECG.Label = "ECG";
            xamChart1.Series.Add(ECG);

            float[] ecg_data = new float[data.Length];
            for(int i = 0; i<ecg_data.Length; i++)
            {
                ecg_data[i] = float.Parse(data[i]);
            }

            for (int i=0; i<4000; i++)
            {
                DataPoint dataPoint=new DataPoint();
                dataPoint.ChartParameters.Add(ChartParameterType.ValueY,ecg_data[i]);
                dataPoint.ChartParameters.Add(ChartParameterType.ValueX,i);
                ECG.DataPoints.Add(dataPoint);
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using the Infragistics xamDataChart control instead of the xamChart.  The xamDataChart was designed to display large amounts of data with high performance.  You should have no trouble displaying 60,000 datapoints.  The xamChart, on the other hand, will usually start to degrade in terms of performance at about 10,000 datapoints.